# How to get data from List<Object[]> using java 8

Tags: java, object, arraylist, java-8

Trying to get a data from DB using JPA. My Data format was like `[[John,Wick,New York],[Walter,White,New Mexico]]`

And am using below code the get the data from `List<Object[]>` and with iteration am getting the each element and setting into my dto like `List<myDto>`

```
List<Object[]> objects = query.list();
    for ( Object[] obj : objects) {
        System.out.println("Data 1"+obj[0]);
        System.out.println("Data 2"+obj[1])
        System.out.println("Data 3"+obj[2])
    }
}
```

instead of doing this, how to achieve the same in java 8 ?

Comment: How is your current code not Java 8?

Comment: Why do you think anything needs to be changed? Is there a specific Java 8 feature you have in mind that you believe will "simplify" the current implementation? Why do you believe that?

Comment: @Unmitigated I didn't used any of the java 8 functional programming methods, and here am using external iterator like forEach loop

Comment: Achieving the same output (with that `"Data 123"` prints) will be quite painful to achieve with streams. You would end up with an `IntStream` that grabs the indices and overall it would not be more readable, dont. If you do not need the `Data 123` extra text, you can flat map.

Answer (score 1):

You code will definitely compile and run on Java 8 compiler and it's also easier to understand. So, I don't think you need anything to improve anything in it.

But just because you asked for it, here is the sample code you can write by adding some Java streams which is "similar" to your code (not exactly same output)

```
objects.forEach(arr -> {
    Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(System.out::println); // please note, it's only printing value on each line
});
```

Comment: Note that you could use `flatMap` to make this code more compact and idomatic.

Answer (score 1):

### Indexed stream

Achieving the same output (with that `"Data 123"` extra text) will be quite painful with streams. You would end up with an `IntStream` that grabs the indices and overall it would not be more readable, dont. Nonetheless, here it is:

```java
query.list().forEach(objects -> {
  IntStream.range(0, objects.length)
    .mapToObj(i -> "Data " + (i + 1) + objects[i])
    .forEach(System.out::println);
});
```

---

### Flattened stream

However, if you do not need the `Data 123` extra text, you can just flat map and it becomes quite compact actually:

```java
query.list()
  .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Object[]> list = query // your list Object[] elements
List<String> transformedList = list.stream()
  .map(objArray -> (String)objArray[0])
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.